# Why do we need event-driven backtesters?

Tags: time-series, quant-trading-strategies, backtesting

I am reading this [article at quantstart](https://www.quantstart.com/articles/Event-Driven-Backtesting-with-Python-Part-I) regarding event-driven backtesters. It seems to me that the main advantage of using an event-driven backtesters is that it avoids look-ahead bias.

Usually I download stock price data at yahoo finance, which contains datetime index on pandas.

But in Python's statsmodels, particularly time series forecasting models such as ARIMA and GARCH, they fit on data nicely.

> Question: Why do we need event-driven backtesters?

Answer (score 2):

You don't *need* an event-driven backtester.

To establish some convention, a function or method that takes a vector as an argument (e.g. a MATLAB function, `statsmodels` API methods) is sometimes interchangeably and confusingly referred to as a *vectorized* function. This doesn't necessarily mean that it uses SIMD *vectorization*, although quite often it is perfectly suited to use SIMD vector extensions given the input data layout - and a modern compiler will exploit that.

Behind the scenes, the said *vectorized* function is simply passing the elements through a loop, just like an event-driven backtester in that sense. So there's no correctness reason for preferring one approach over another.

However, the main upside of wrapping this loop around an event-driven backtester rather than a vectorized function is that the former is identical to how you'll implement it for production data (which comes streaming in 1 event at a time) whereas the latter needs to be modified to handle streaming, realtime data.

There's also a small upside in that vectorized functions tend to make it hard to reason around the sequence of events and avoid lookahead bias - chances are that all you need is an off-by-one indexing error to cause severe harm to the accuracy of your backtest, whereas it's quite impossible to make this mistake if you are processing the elements in an event-driven manner.

Comment: SIMD refers to Single Instruction, Multiple Data.

Answer (score 2):

The two types of backtesters have slightly different purposes.

The vectorised backtest is a rather crude way to quickly test a strategy. You do it by multiplying the signal vector with the returns vector and the result is the equity curve.

The event-driven backtester is a more well thought out simulation. By making use of an event driven backtester we can stop look ahead bias to a large extent by only feeding in the data as it becomes available. This also very closely matches how your trading will take place in real life via an execution system.

We also have the advantage of building in transaction costs, liquidity constraints, and market impact. This is not something you can do with the vectorized method. (You could add transaction costs after the fact).

The event driven system you refer to from quantstart has the added advantage that you can swap out your backtester for a live model rather easily by just changing a parameter. It already creates a blotter, accounting system, pre and post performance metrics. Event driven is the way to go if you want to build out an institutional grade infrastructure.

Vectorised backtesters are for quick research ideas but if you have an event driven one, then you can forget about vectorised...

Oh and I know of funds that have implemented the event-driven architecture and I have used it personally. It's the way to go.